# 14.04 aborts in the middle of installation, but somehow works fine

Tags: upgrade

Last night I've tried upgrading my system to v14.04. The system aborted the upgrade about three hours in, saying that there were some files unable to be installed, and it said something along the lines of "run `dpkg -a`". Neither `dpkg` nor `apt-get` worked, so I rebooted my PC, and expected the worst.

My PC seemed to actually work fine after rebooting, and even confirmed that it was indeed running v14.04, which is also the reason why the command `do-release-upgrade` doesn't work. However, I feel that the upgrade is incomplete, though I have also done `update-manager -d`, just to be on the safe side. Is there anything else I should to to make sure nothing is broken or corrupted?

Comment: `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: Those commands did just what I needed to do. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The OP said that Braiam's solution in the comment solved the problem:
`sudo dpkg --configure` -a and `sudo apt-get -f install`.